# Describing a Subset of a Hilbert Space $H$

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. How can we describe the set $\{ x \in H \mid \|x-y\| = a \|x-z\| \},$ where $y, z \in H$ are fixed and $a > 0$? Geometrically how does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Square the inner products and work things out. Then, for $a≠1$ and modulo computational mistakes:
\begin{equation*}
\parallel x-\frac{y-a^{2}z}{1-a^{2}}\parallel =c,
\end{equation*}
where $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\|x-y\|$ denotes that distance from the point $x$ to the point $y$.

$\|x-z\|$ denotes that distance from the point $x$ to the point $z$.

Comment: Is there a connection with the Appolonius sphere?

Comment: Sorry I don't know Appolonius sphere;

Comment: However, you can view a Hilbert space as a metric space, especially $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

It look like the hyperplane parpendicular to the line joining $y$ and $z$ and dividing the line in the proportion $a:(1-a)$.